# jupyterhub server error invalid cookie_secret_file

Tags: server, localhost, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm trying to make jupyterhub web application interface for real-time collaboration and multi-user modification( they will work together at the same local network). On window I can't make this interface then I use WSL2 on Windows and now trying to start locally Jupyterhub server it gives me this error:

madina@DESKTOP-D0HQMCO:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ jupyterhub

[I 2024-01-14 23:53:32.156 JupyterHub app:2859] Running JupyterHub version 4.0.2
[I 2024-01-14 23:53:32.156 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-4.0.2
[I 2024-01-14 23:53:32.156 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-4.0.2
[I 2024-01-14 23:53:32.156 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Proxy: jupyterhub.proxy.ConfigurableHTTPProxy-4.0.2
[I 2024-01-14 23:53:32.167 JupyterHub app:1664] Loading cookie_secret from /mnt/c/Windows/system32/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[E 2024-01-14 23:53:32.169 JupyterHub app:1694] Refusing to run JupyterHub with invalid cookie_secret_file. /mnt/c/Windows/system32/jupyterhub_cookie_secret error was: cookie_secret_file can be read or written by anybody

im aspecting it should run on my local port 8000.